# In django, can I show post's permalink in admin page?

Tags: django

I have a model called Post for my Blog application in Django. I have a slug field that is prepopulated by the title field. (I also use the get_absolute_url method, if that matters). What I want is to be able to see the permalink, of course without being able to edit it! Just readonly. I also believe that this field will be empty when I create a post, so only visible-active when I update a post.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you define `get_absolute_url` method on your model and add the model to the admin site using `ModelAdmin` you should already see a link on the right, top saying "View on site". (like on this image: https://www.webforefront.com/static/images/django/setupdjangomodelsindjangoadmin_screenshot36.png) Isn't that what you want to do?

Comment: No I want a field "permalink' that will auto show www.mysite.com/blog/post/slug,the corresponding url of each post.